# jQuery Ajax get request (specific data)

Tags: python, jquery, ajax

I want to get some data from my python file, but when I use the ajax get request I get the whole python file. I only want some variables, do I have to change my ajax request or do I have to add something to my python file.

Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'mail.py',
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your ajax script interact with some python program, you should consider your python program to be able to receive HTTP requests.

Flask is a python framework for doing that in a very easy manner. If you are not familiar with HTTP requests, consider reading about GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests. Flask supports them all.

Related: [Flask and Ajax](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/)